# How does ARIMAX in statsmodels.api compute the confidence intervals?

Tags: arima

I performed an ARIMAX model on a time serie but I am getting a very large Confidence interval and I was wondering how are they calculated. Because the lower CI is very low

[image]

Here is the code I used :

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

y=series

x=np.array(series.index)

resultat = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                order=(7, 2, 2),
                                enforce_stationarity=True,
                                enforce_invertibility=True).fit()

pred_uc = resultat.get_forecast(steps=1700)

pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int()

plt.plot(pred_uc.predicted_mean, label='Forecast before reset', color='#ff0066')

plt.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='#ff0066', alpha=.25)
```

Comment: Show some code / output?

Comment: *Confidence interval* (for a parameter estimate) or *forecast interval* / *prediction interval* (for a forecast/prediction)? Please add the relevant tag (one of the two).

Comment: I did some modification to make the question clear